# After login Desktop not showing 16.04

Tags: unity, 16.04, login-screen, .desktop, katoolin

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and I have installed Kali linux tools on top of that using Katoolin, after restarting I can enter the password but desktop showing blank no icons. I used below command but it didn't work:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

[image]